# Setup of DG4SQL Gateway from Oracle 11.2 to SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, oracle11g, heterogeneous

First, I am new to using Oracle and need to make a connection from Oracle 11.2 to SQL Server 2005.  I have read many articles, but I still can't setup a heterogeneous connection.  I am asking for any help, please??  Thanks in Advance

The error displayed is ORA-12154

I am using one pc running Windows 7, which has windows virtual xp.
Oracle is installed on on the XP virtual machine and SQL 2005 is installed on the windows 7 machine (64 bit).

Listed are my entries from tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and initdg4sql.ora:

tnsnames.ora

```
dg4msql=
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = VirtualXP-28481)(PORT = 1521))
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = dg4msql)
)
(HS = OK)
)
```

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
     (SID_NAME = dg4msql)
     (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\XPMUser\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
     (PROGRAM = dg4msql)
   )
  )
LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
   )
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = VirtualXP-28481)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\XPMUser
```

initdg4sql.ora

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO=[inspiron]//Academic
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=OFF
HS_FDS_RECOVERY_ACCOUNT=RECOVER
HS_FDS_RECOVERY_PWD=RECOVER
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..... I've done more research and found that I can't login to SQL Plus, SQL Developer or SQL tools using the db server, but I am able to login using the client. From the client side, the Global Name matches the TNSNames.ora file

Answer (score 1):

The ORA-12154 is a very common error, always related to your local copy of the tnsnames.ora file, your listener configuration and your database name aliases.

- Make sure that your listener is listening for the same service name that you are using.
- Your service name might have an alias, so check for global (world) entries and local entries.  Check:

  `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`
- Check your global_name setting with this SQL:

  `select * from global_name;`

The query value should match your init.ora parms for db_name and db_domain

([source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12154_tns_resolve_service_name.htm))